# Как можно получить список городов для конкретной страны на андроид?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, геолокация

Мне нужно получить список городов по стране на андроиде. Например вводим Венгрия и получаем респонс со всеми городами этой страны, желательно на русском языке. Есть ли какое-то решение ?

Answer (score 0):

90% IP2Country баз обладают нужным тебе списком городов, сёл, и.т.д. Обычно их себестоимость в районе 5$ за более или менее вкусную базу. Если проект совсем бюджетный, или хочется постоянных обновлений то попроси знакомого сисадмина что-бы тебе скинул, или попробуй из других GeoLocation источников. Потом просто парсером сожми в SQLite базу и закинь себе в jar'ку.

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities) лежит нужная вам БД

Закинуть его на SQLite и написать запрос не составит особого труда.

Только учтите [лицензию](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)

Формат данных простой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]